# Polymer v.1 - How to run a function from outside Polymer({....});

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

if i have

```
Polymer({
      is: 'whatever',
      myFunction: function () {
      alert("ok");
  }
});
```

How do run `myFunction` from outside `Polymer({ .. });`

Is that possible?

the normal java-script way would be `myFunction()` but i understand Polymer works differently.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reference the module on the page and call the method.

```
document.querySelector("whatever").myFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks.  crap, i had a # - i was trying this -- document.querySelector("#my-request").setajax()

Comment: Well it would have worked if you have that id on the element. :)

Comment: The id is on (<dom-module id="my-request")